# Are the limits on "limited edition" NFTs enforced by ERC 721?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, nft

I was looking at the ERC-721Enumerable interface, and I couldn't anything in the interface where say, an edition of 5 tokens for some NFT is actually enforced by the contract.

Is that true, do we just need to rely on good faith of the minter that he won't mint more tokens that he claims when he sells the edition in the first place.  Can he go back a month later and mint 10 more identical NFTs of the same work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe.

A contract CAN enforce some limit on a specific usage pattern of token identifiers. The standard does not include this by default.

But don't forget, nothing stops somebody from creating a new contract or switching to a different blockchain and selling the same thing.

Reputation and trust are important for all digital assets.

Comment: Yes a little problematic for a ecosystem thats supposed to be trustless.   When you say the standard does not include this by default, would be accurate to say the standard doesnt include it at all?  I undestand you could modify the contract to enforce a limit on the number of tokens it creates, but  I take it there's no defined function in the sstandard  which you can call to find out the limit, correct?

Comment: @GGizmos I think so

Comment: The standard does not include this feature. You can add this feature to your implementation and remain compatible with the standard.

Comment: Ethereum and blockchain are NOT designed or supposed to be trustless. Whoever told you that, be sure to get your money back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are correct a minter can mint any number of NFT tokens of same work whenever he/she wanted. Because the implementation of ERC721 don't check the work of an minter. But, If you want implement Such thing like checking If an NFT token is already minted, you can do like that by using ERC721 as a base for your smart contract. That is also possible!!

Answer (score 0):

All ERC-721 NFTs are one-offs. So if you mint 5 NFTs as editions for a piece, there's nothing stopping you from minting a 6th.

However, if you use ERC-1155, you can specifically limit the number of editions to 5.

(There's nothing stopping the artist from creating another ERC-1155 NFT with however many editions they want, but at least the original will always be 5 of 5)